# How can I get a logged in user's firebase metadata in react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have used firebase to authenticate a user inside my app. However getting their metadata to show last sign in date and account creation data has been a hassle. The documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usermetadata#usermetadatacreationtime) doesn't help much. Is quite confusing.

I know I can import {UserMetadata} from "firebase/auth" but whatever I've tried after that does not work. It seems like the documentation is based on Typescript and I've been getting errors.

I am expeting to get the metadata in a similar format to this if possible

```
<div className="membership_start_date account_overview_card">
   <h2 className='account_overview_card_title'>Member since</h2>
   <p className='account_overview_card_detail'>{metadata}</p>
</div>
```

I have tried importing UserMetaData in this way:

```
import {UserMetadata} from "firebase/auth"

const Account = () => {
  const metadata = UserMetadata()

  return (
     <p className='account_overview_card_detail'>{metadata.lastSignIn}</p>
  )
}
export default Account
```

The whole code is quite long so I've tried to resume it to the most necessary part. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

UserMetadata is part of a `user` object. Assuming you already have sign in method. Then in auth state subscription method you can access user's data:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unregisterAuthObserver = getAuth(firebaseApp).onAuthStateChanged(
      async (authUser) => {
        if (authUser) {
          // authUser.metadata?.creationTime <--- here
          // authUser.metadata?.lastSignInTime <-- and here
        }
      },
    );

     // Make sure we un-register Firebase observers when the component unmounts.
    return () => unregisterAuthObserver(); 
  }, [firebaseApp]);
```

You can even test a short version having firebase globally set up:

```
getAuth().currentUser?.metadata
```

Comment: I have firebase installed globally so your answer worked for me. Thanks, Artur!

Answer (score 0):

### First make sure you has fbAuth properly exported:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from "firebase/functions";
import { getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from "firebase/firestore";

import fbConfig from "../../firebase.json";

export const fbApp = initializeApp({
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
});

export const fbFunctions = getFunctions(fbApp);

export const fbAuth = getAuth(fbApp);

export const db = getFirestore(fbApp);

if (import.meta.env.DEV) {
  connectFunctionsEmulator(
    fbFunctions,
    "localhost",
    fbConfig.emulators.functions.port
  );
  connectAuthEmulator(
    fbAuth,
    `http://localhost:${fbConfig.emulators.auth.port}`
  );
  connectFirestoreEmulator(db, `localhost`, fbConfig.emulators.firestore.port);
}
```

### Then call at some point your desired authentication method:

```
import { ref } from "vue";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
import { fbAuth } from "../config/firebase";

export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", () => {

  const user = ref({ uid: null });
  const lastUser = localStorage.getItem("lastUser");

  if (lastUser) {
    user.value = JSON.parse(lastUser);
  }

  const fbLogin = (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    if (!user.value || !user.value.uid) {
      const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
      signInWithPopup(fbAuth, provider).then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        const {
          accessToken,
          displayName,
          email,
          emailVerified,
          isAnonymous,
          uid
        } = result.user;
        user.value = result.user;
        localStorage.setItem(
          "lastUser",
          JSON.stringify({
            accessToken,
            displayName,
            email,
            emailVerified,
            isAnonymous,
            uid
          })
        );
      });
    } else {
      signOut(fbAuth).then((e) => {
        user.value = { uid: null };
        console.log(e);
        console.log("user sign out");
        localStorage.removeItem("lastUser");
      });
    }
  };

  return { user, fbLogin };
});
```

### Finally chek on your current user:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Authenticate</h1>
    <button @click="userStore.fbLogin">Login/Logout</button>
    <p v-if="userStore?.user && userStore?.user?.uid">
      Hello, {{ userStore?.user?.displayName }}!
    </p>
    <p v-else>Not logged</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile
import { useUserStore } from "../stores/user";

const userStore = useUserStore();
</script>
```

Full source code [here](https://github.com/sombriks/sample-firebase). It's written in vue but the general idea is very similar to it.